# how to keep a specific string in php without split

Tags: php

I have a string like this : `xxxxxxx=921919291&arg3=3729ABNTSC980z2MNM3573&arg2=2025102&arg1=7e266505e183fcb31d0ba493008fa9f881af6746`.

i want to keep only the `xxxxxxx=921919291` (this one is variable so i can't use an strpos)

I have tried an explode of `&` caractere then show only the 0 one but i have a lot of string in the same variable so it would not but good.

`STR_REPLACE` dosn't seems to be good because all caracteres after the `=` caractere are variable.

Comment: Is it always only going to be the first parameter?

Comment: @andrewsi yes exactly

Comment: Could these parameters become re-ordered in the future? (Is it a GET request, can you just use `$_GET['xxxxxxx']`?)

Comment: Then use strpos to find the first ampersand, and substr to read that many characters.

Comment: Or `explode('&', $string, 1)` [shamelessly stolen from an excellent answer on a similar question I saw this morning]

Comment: use `parse_str()` then pop off the first element of the resulting array?

Comment: @andrewsi the problem is my string have more a lot of caracteres it's something like : `$string = "xxxxxxx=921919291&arg3=3729ABNTSC980z2MNM3573&arg2=2025102&arg1=7e266505e183fcb31d0ba493008fa9f881af6746\nxxxxxxx=921919291&arg3=3729ABNTSC980z2MNM3573&arg2=2025102&arg1=7e266505e183fcb31d0ba493008fa9f881af6746\n\xxxxxxx=921919291&arg3=3729ABNTSC980z2MNM3573&arg2=2025102&arg1=7e266505e183fcb31d0ba493008fa9f881af6746"`

Comment: @KniizaBen - I'm not sure why the length of the string makes any difference

Comment: because i want to keep only `xxxxxxx=921919291` whish is content more than one time in the String and having all of them.

Comment: so you mean 'xxxxxxx' can have more than one value?

Comment: it's just like i want to do a `str_replace("&arg3=xxxxxxxx","",$string)` and same thing with all other arg but the xxxxx is variable .

Comment: But both of my suggested methods, as well as Marc B's, would just return the first item in your array. It doesn't matter how many times the string appears elsewhere.

Comment: @KniizaBen - that's not what your question says. And when I asked if it was always the first parameter you were looking for, you said it was.

Comment: yeah. question is a bit vague.. can't say who is correct or if we are on the same path as the OP.

Comment: Remember to mark the best answer to your question to help future users!

Answer (score 8):

use parse_str

```
$str = "xxxxxxx=921919291&arg3=3729ABNTSC980z2MNM3573&arg2=2025102&arg1=7e266505e183fcb31d0ba493008fa9f881af6746";
parse_str($str);
echo $xxxxxxx;
```

You can also place your values into an array like so:

```
$str = "xxxxxxx=921919291&arg3=3729ABNTSC980z2MNM3573&arg2=2025102&arg1=7e266505e183fcb31d0ba493008fa9f881af6746";
parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['xxxxxxx'];
```

More information can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: this one would be the safest afaik.. without needing regex. +1 for this

Comment: Thanks! It has helped me out of many problems before. A very handy tool!

Comment: i think he did just that on the second example.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo array_shift(explode('&', $string));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [phps capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html), an expression like this, should sort you:

```
^([^&]+)
```

This will populate capture group 1, which is accessed using the parameter of the preg_match call as an array element.